# On cutting disks from planar regions

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, circle-packing

**Question:** Given a planar region $R$ of unit area and an integer $n$, to cut $n$ circular disks (their sizes need not be equal) such that the highest fraction of $R$ is taken off.

A simple greedy algorithm would be to repeatedly cut the biggest disk that can be cut at each stage from what remains of $R$. I don't know of any $R$ and $n$ where this algorithm clearly fails to give an optimal result. Ideally, one is looking for a convex $R$ and some $n$ such that the greedy algorithm clearly fails.

**Remarks:** If from a given $R$, instead of disks, $n$ triangles or $n$ squares are to be cut such that max fraction of $R$ is to be removed, 'greedy' clearly fails in general. For simple examples, see [R.Nandakumar's blog](http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2020/12/breaking-pieces-from-polygons.html).

One can ask whether the problem of cutting say $n$ triangles off from a unit area $m$-gon is NP complete.

**Note (18th Jan, 2021):** One can also ask about **covering** a given $R$ with a specified number of disks (which could be of different sizes) such that the least portion of the covering disks go waste - and with say, squares instead of disks.

Comment: 3 circles, touching, arranged in a triangle, then take $R$ the convex hull scaled to area 1 and $n=3$?

Comment: yes, checked it! that was a possibility that I had overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: This question is closely related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/115455/

Comment: A slightly better version, 3 discs radius $1$, $1+\epsilon$, $1$ with centres at $(-1, 0)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $R$ the convex hull of these.  The greedy algorithm will choose the centre disk first, then a radius $(1-\epsilon)/2$ disc, compare this to the pair of outer discs.  For $\epsilon = 0$, $R$ has area $\pi + 4$, the "greedy selection" (which the greedy algorithm might not choose for $\epsilon=0$) is $5\pi/4$, the outer selection is $2\pi$.  Let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for inequalities with these values as bounds in the greedy case.