# A Variant of the Malfatti Problem

Tags: discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

See [the Wikipedia entry on Malfatti circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles) for an introduction to Malfatti's problem.

The above page also states that for $n >3$, the question of whether a greedy method (at each step, the method cuts the biggest possible circular disc out of what remains of the triangle) yields $n$ discs within any triangle such that the discs together cover max portion of the triangle is unsolved.

**Question:** For the case of cutting regular polygons all with a specified number $m$ of sides from any given triangle, and with $n = 3$, does a greedy approach result in $n$ regular $m$-gons that together cover the highest fraction of the triangle? If not, will greedy work only for regular polygons with say, even number of sides?

**Note:** For cutting even 3 discs of max total area from convex polygons other than triangles, greedy can fail. An example is given in the " [On cutting disks from planar regions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380035/on-cutting-disks-from-planar-regions) "
Q&A. But I don't know the situation for say, cutting 3 discs of max total area from a convex *quadrilateral*.

*A further question, probably a slight variant on the open problem on the above Wiki page (October 2023):* for a given $n$, finding a layout of $n$ disks of suitable radii such that the least area triangular sheet from which the disks can be cut has the largest fraction of its area utilized. For any $n$, is the optimal triangular sheet equilateral and the $n$-disk layout that uses the most of it the one got by the above greedy method?