# Optimal packing and covering of a triangle with squares

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, packing-and-covering

We continue from [Another variant of the Malfatti problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456324/another-variant-of-the-malfatti-problem).

1. Given a triangle T and a number n, how to cover it with n squares (of possibly different dimensions) such that the sum of the areas (perimeters) of the squares is minimized?
2. Given T and n, to pack into it n squares such that the sum of the areas (perimeters) of the squares is a maximum.

**Guess:** For any given T, if we consider n **rectangles** instead of squares, a least total area (perimeter) covering (packing) layout will consist of a 'stack' of n rectangles of same width and  same orientation as the single rectangle of smallest area (perimeter) that contains (is contained within) T. *Note:* It can be shown that the smallest area rectangle and smallest perimeter rectangle containing a triangle can have widely different orientations.